# Select box shows no value when binding form component

Tags: angular

Selectbox only shows default value but not other value from component.I am trying to show the accType value in selectbox.Am i doing something wrong? I am new to angular. Please help.

Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AccType } from '../models/accType';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-account-form',
  templateUrl: './account-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./account-form.component.css']
})
export class AccountFormComponent implements OnInit {

    accTypes = [
        { id: "S", name: "Supplier" },
        { id: "C", name: "Customer" }
    ];


    ngOnInit() {

        console.log("AccType",this.accTypes);
  }

}
```

Html:

```
    <h2>Create new Account</h2>
<br />
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Account Name</label>
        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="accountName" required>
            <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="accountName.touched && !accountName.valid">Please provide account name</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="accType" class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Account Type</label>
        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
            <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="accType.id">
                <option value="">Select Accout Type</option>
                <option *ngFor="let accType of accTypes" [ngValue]="accType"> {{accType.name}} </option>
            </select>
            <!-- <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="accType.touched && !accType.valid">Please specify the supplier</div>-->
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: it looks good https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-select-example-ngfor-vedoak?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Suddenly it shows value.Don't know what was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selected" name="status" placeholder="select" (ngModelChange)="onOptionsSelected()">
        <option *ngFor="let sta of accTypes" [ngValue]="sta.id">{{sta.name}}</option>
    </select>
<div>
  {{filtered|json}}
</div>

/*************** ts file ***************/
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
 selected:any = 'S';
filtered :any;
    accTypes = [
        { id: "S", name: "Supplier" },
        { id: "C", name: "Customer" }
    ];

constructor() {

        }

onOptionsSelected() {
 console.log(this.selected);  
    }
}
```